# Getting initial content into an app on installation

Tags: ios

I'm making an iOS app that will have updatable content, and I want to include some initial content with the app installation.  Knowing content placed in the main bundle can't be modified, where should I store this initial content, and how could I get it there, short of downloading it on initial launch?

Comment: You need to add more details. What type of content? Are you storing it in a database? Are you using CoreData?

Comment: Hi @MarkM.  No CoreData.  This is data I would normally download on first launch (think a news app), but due to some earlier engineering decisions, the spec calls for it being in the bundle as a manual include for app launch...I know it is not the best method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content in the main bundle can't be *modified*, but it can certainly be *copied* to your user's documents folder and used from there. In your `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or similar on-startup method, you can:

1. Get the path to the desired documents folder/file
2. Check if any of your downloaded content already exists at that path

   1. If not, copy your special resource from the main bundle to the documents folder
   2. If so, just keep going - you already have content
3. Continue by downloading updates or whatever else your app needs from the network

Comment: Excellent idea...only problem is the content is huge.  The app would take up double the space it should.  But in all honesty, I don't know if there's a way around it, thinking about it.

Comment: It's the only way I can see, also.